# Definition of closed walks on a graph. How to enumerate the vertices?

Tags: graph-theory

> In my definition, this is a closed walk? If yes, how can I enumerate the vertices? In this picture, who is $v_1, v_2,...$?

Definition: A closed walk in a graph is defined to be ordered collection of vertices $(v_1,v_2,...,v_n)$ such that $v_i$ and $v_{i+1}$ are neighbours for all $1 \leq i \leq n-1$, and $v_n$ and $v_1$ are neighbours. Note that the walk is allowed to visit the same vertex or traverse the same edge on more than one occasion.[image]

Comment: No, the picture is not a closed walk, because a closed walk is a sequence of vertices, and the picture is not a sequence of vertices.

Comment: @MishaLavrov could you give me an example of closed walk that we have at least two visits the same vertex and/or at least two traverse the same edge? I can't imagine an example. Thanks

Comment: Get a "triangle" graph with vertices $v_1,\, v_2,\, v_3$. $(v_1,\, v_2,\, v_3, \,v_1,\, v_2,\, v_3)$ is one of such closed walks.